# Neural network with 'tanh' as activation and 'cross-entropy' as cost function did not work

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I have implemented a simple neural network. It works well with 'sigmoid + cross-entropy', 'sigmoid + quadratic cost', and 'tanh + quadratic cost', but it did not work with 'tanh + cross-entropy' (no better than randomly guess).  Can anybody please help me figure out why? Just see the code of FullConnectedLayer:

```
class FullConnectedLayer(BaseLayer):
    """
    FullConnectedLayer
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Data members: 
    sizes       ---- <type list> sizes of the network
    n_layers    ---- <type int> number of sublayers
    activation  ---- <type Activation> activation function for neurons
    weights     ---- <type list> to store weights
    biases      ---- <type list> to store biases
    neurons     ---- <type list> to store states (outputs) of neurons
    zs          ---- <type list> to store weighted inputs to neurons
    grad_w      ---- <type list> to store gradient of Cost w.r.t weights
    grad_b      ---- <type list> to store gradient of Cost w.r.t biases
    ---------------------
    Methods:
    __init__(self, sizes, activation = Sigmoid())
    size(self)
    model(self)
    feedforward(self, a)
    backprop(self, C_p)
    update(self, eta, lmbda, batch_size, n)
    """

    def __init__(self, sizes, activation = Sigmoid(), normal_initialization = False):
        """
        The list ''sizes'' contains the number of neurons in repective layers
        of the network. For example, sizes = [2, 3, 2] represents 3 layers, with
        the first layer having 2 neurons, the second 3 neurons, and the third 2 
        neurons.

        Note that the input layer may be passed by other layer of another type 
        when connected after the layer, and we don't set biases for this layer.
        Also note that the output layer my be passed to other layer if connected
        before the layer, in this case, just assign the outputs to its inputs.
        For examle, Layer1([3, 2, 4])->Layer2([4, 6, 3])->Layer3([3, 2]). Just
        assign the output of Layer1 to the input Layer2, it will be safe.
        """

        BaseLayer.__init__(self, sizes, activation)

        if normal_initialization:
            self.weights = [np.random.randn(j, i)
                    for i, j in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
        else:
            self.weights = [np.random.randn(j, i) / np.sqrt(i)
                    for i, j in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
        self.biases = [np.random.randn(j, 1) for j in sizes[1:]]

        self.grad_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
        self.grad_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]

    def feedforward(self, a):
        """
        Return output of the network if ''a'' is input.
        """
        self.neurons = [a] # to store activations (outputs) of all layers
        self.zs = []
        for w, b in zip(self.weights, self.biases):
            z = np.dot(w, self.neurons[-1]) + b
            self.zs.append(z)
            self.neurons.append(self.activation.func(z))
        return self.neurons[-1]


    def backprop(self, Cp_a):
        """
        Backpropagate the delta error.
        ------------------------------
        Return a tuple whose first component is a list of the gradients of 
        weights and biases, whose second component is the backpropagated delta.
        Cp_a, dC/da: derivative of cost function w.r.t a, output of neurons. 
        """
        # The last layer
        delta = Cp_a * self.activation.prime(self.zs[-1])
        self.grad_b[-1] += delta
        self.grad_w[-1] += np.dot(delta, self.neurons[-2].transpose()) 

        for l in range(2, self.n_layers):
            sp = self.activation.prime(self.zs[-l])  # a.prime(z)
            delta = np.dot(self.weights[-l + 1].transpose(), delta) * sp  
            self.grad_b[-l] += delta
            self.grad_w[-l] += np.dot(delta, self.neurons[-l - 1].transpose())

        Cp_a_out = np.dot(self.weights[0].transpose(), delta)

        return Cp_a_out

    def update(self, eta, lmbda, batch_size, n):
        """
        Update the network's weights and biases by applying gradient descent
        algorithm.
        ''eta'' is the learning rate
        ''lmbda'' is the regularization parameter
        ''n'' is the total size of the training data set
        """
        self.weights = [(1 - eta * (lmbda/n)) * w - (eta/batch_size) * delta_w\
                for w, delta_w in zip(self.weights, self.grad_w)]
        self.biases = [ b - (eta / batch_size) * delta_b\
                for b, delta_b in zip(self.biases, self.grad_b)]

        # Clear ''grad_w'' and ''grad_b'' so that they are not added to the 
        # next update pass
        for dw, db in zip(self.grad_w, self.grad_b):
            dw.fill(0)
            db.fill(0)
```

Here is the code of the tanh function:

```
class Tanh(Activation):

    @staticmethod
    def func(z):
        """ The functionality. """
        return (np.exp(z) - np.exp(-z)) / (np.exp(z) + np.exp(-z))

    @staticmethod
    def prime(z):
        """ The derivative. """
        return 1. - Tanh.func(z) ** 2
```

And here is the code of cross-entropy class:

```
class CrossEntropyCost(Cost):

    @staticmethod
    def func(a, y):
        """
        Return the cost associated with an output ''a'' and desired output
        ''y''. 
        Note that np.nan_to_num is used to ensure numerical stability. In
        particular, if both ''a'' and ''y'' have a 1.0 in the same slot, 
        then the expression (1-y) * np.log(1-a) returns nan. The np.nan_to_num
        ensures that that is converted to the correct value(0.0).
        """
        for ai in a:
            if ai < 0:
                print("in CrossEntropyCost.func(a, y)... require a_i > 0, a_i belong to a.")
                exit(1)

        return np.sum(np.nan_to_num(-y * np.log(a) - (1-y) * np.log(1-a)))

    @staticmethod
    def Cp_a(a, y):
        """
        Cp_a, dC/da: the derivative of C w.r.t a
        ''a'' is the output of neurons
        ''y'' is the expected output of neurons
        """
        #return (a - y) # delta
        return (a - y) / (a * (1 - a))
```

---

Edit:
    Seems the problem is that the range of `tanh` is `-1` to `+1`, which is illegal for cross-entropy. But if I just want a `tanh` activation and a cross-entropy cost, how should I deal with it?

Comment: Removed DNN and CNN tags; this is neither deep nor convolutional. Looks like python, please tag with language used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using `tanh` in your output layer, where `tanh` has the range `-1, +1` and the expected outputs are in the range `0, +1`. This doesn't matter for the `Sigmoid` which does produce outputs in the range `0, +1`.

Comment: since the derivative of cross-entropy `-[ylog(a) +  (1-y)log(1-a)]` w.r.t `a` have nothing to do with `log`, why dose it matter to have a range `-1` to `+1`?

Comment: Oh...I'm sorry, seems I make a mistake with calculus.... indeed... `a` must be  in the range `0` to `-1` for a cross-entropy...

Comment: Well, 0 < a < +1, `log(a)` isn't defined for a<=0 and `log(1-a)` isn't defined for a>=1.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give any advice to deal with this problem if I do want a `tanh` and cross-entropy?

Comment: No, sorry - the "obvious" fix would be to use `1/2 + 1/2tanh(1/2x)` but that's the Sigmoid in disguise. You must have a non-mathematical reason to choose the `tanh` over the sigmoid, it seems, but I can't guess that reason or give an advice based on that reason.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is late but I think it's worth mentioning.

If you want to use a tanh activation function, instead of using a cross-entropy cost function, you can modify it to give outputs between -1 and 1.

The same would look something like:

((1 + y)/2 * log(a)) + ((1-y)/2 * log(1-a))

Using this as the cost function will let you use the tanh activation.

Comment: It looks as if you're scaling the labels instead of the network outputs.

I think what you were going for was: `y*log((1+a)/2)+(1-y)*log((1-a)/2)`

Answer (score 2):

Cross entropy expects it's inputs to be logits, which are in the range 0 to 1.
The Tanh method transforms the input to values in the range -1 to 1 which cross entropy can't handle.

Some possible fixes would be to rescale the input in the final layer in the input is tanh and the cost cross-entropy.

Comment: Sorry... I didn't quite understand your last sentence

Comment: Rescaling the output of tanh to [0, 1] is `(x + 1) / 2` so `[-1, 1] -> [0, 1]`